# How to disable tab animations in Chrome?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome

Is it possible to disable tab animations in Chrome? I think they're annoying; when I'm trying to close multiple tabs at once, the animation can cause me to miss the X and navigate to the actual content of the tab. I've Googled for a solution to this, but I can't find one.